# hosting a webserver locally with apache on windows

Tags: apache, localhost, web-hosting

I have been searching for a while now and I have not found what i am looking for! I have installed apache on my local server and I have set up port forwarding, but I don't know how to connect my localhost to the internet were everyone can view it. I do have a domain already too. I just need to know how to point it to my local server. If you could tell me or point me in the right direction on what I need to do. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have static or dynamic IP address?

Comment: I have a static I think.

Comment: Keep in mind that (after you fill-in your A-record as @sibi explained) you have to wait 12-24 hours for domain propagation. Also, check your firewall settings, it will probably block access to your computer.

Comment: my firewall settings are good I allowed apache publicly, but I cant even access my server publicly though

Comment: thanks found out what was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If others on the internet can already access your server via a public IP, then go to your domain registrar (like godaddy), and point your domain to your public IP.

Comment: people cant access my server publicly though, that's what I need help with thanks for helping though.

Comment: I thought you already set up port forwarding on your router. If not, you just need to direct the router's port (usually port 80) to your server. see http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Apache/ for more help

Comment: I think I did I might have messed it up so let me check that

Comment: I have to mention that hosting from home is subject to a lot of malicious attacks. AWS has a free one year plan, you might want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

The exact procedure depends a bit on your internet provider, but usually you have to log onto the management site of the provider where your domain is registered and then set up the correct DNS records.
In your case, it should be the so-called "A Record"

DNS records are used to control the location of a resource on the Internet. As an example, An A Record is used to point a logical domain name, such as "google.com", to the IP address of Google's hosting server, "74.125.224.147".
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/a_record

I hope this helps to point you into the right direction.